# RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo doesn't work if we use Android Data Binding in ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-databinding

I've implemented `RecyclerView.Adaper` using Android Data Binding library like in [tutorial](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4): in `onCreateViewHolder` I do `ViewItemBinding.inflate` in `onBindViewHolder` I update view model in bindings.

When I use `RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(hasDescendant(withText(textId))))
```

**It throws PerformException**

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: has descendant: with string from resource id: <2131689508>[activity_home_item_title] value: The title' on view 'with id: com.xxx.yyy.debug:id/recyclerView'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

As a fast workaround you can `executePendingBindings` in `onBindViewHolder`

```
viewDataBinding.viewModel = myViewModel
viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings()
```

**Explanation**

When you set model to viewBindigns under the hood Android Data Bindings calls `ViewDataBinding.requestRebind` which requests chareorgrapher execute bindings in the next frame. So at the time when Espresso match text, bindings isn't applied yet, i.e. view didn't get data from view model yet.

If you're looking for an alternative and let's say more 'clean' approach you can try to `executePendingBindings` in your `ViewHolderMatcher`, it should work but it requires more effort and I didn't try it.